# Is it possible to play CEO and VIP stuff in a lobby with only organisation members?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I don't have that much money to become one. So, Im wondering if I can become an CEO or VIP then can I deliver packages etc in a lobby where only my organisation members are present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sadly, no, for these things to work you need to be in an Open Lobby**, otherwise you won't be able to do anything regarding CEO or VIP activity.

There is a small chance that when you try to play online, you spawn in an open but empty lobby, in where your organisation members can join and do these types of mission alone, happened to me a few times already.

Note: I am only sure about the CEO stuff, If the VIP stuff is different i am sorry for my false information and I'll edit this answer accordingly if someone can tell me that this is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

While you can't do any CEO work in a Solo or Invite Only sessions (you're prevented from logging on to the CEO computer), as of jan/2017, **you can do VIP work in private lobbies** without any problems. I do it all the time.

Comment: That too limited vip work I guess like wanted level, package missions etc

Answer (score 2):

Yes go to any public session and on xbox test your NAT type .  It'll kick everyone out but you from the session and you can now collect crates hassle free.

If you are on PC or PS4 search public solo lobby GTA on youtube and there sound be a few videos on it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately as of a few days ago Rockstar gamed fixed so you can't do the nat test to be in a public lobby by yourself so now you have to try doing all your ceo and mc work in a lobby with everyone makes it next to impossible to sell you're stock from your businesses its annoying because even if you aren't bothering anyone someone always comes an messes it up and destroys you're stock

Comment: And vehicles with missiles are making the situation worse

Answer (score 1):

Things may have changed over time but as of 2020 you can do a handful of VIP missions in a solo lobby and can enjoy the vehicle drop offs etc. But the actual bunker-based delivery missions require you to be in a public lobby as the bunker computer doesn’t work in private (or, at least, invite only which is what I think is being talked about here.